# An efficient approach to combinations of pairs in groups without repetitions?

Tags: ruby, combinations, combinatorics

Before I start, I need to admit that I am not a mathematician and if possible would need this explained in laymen terms. I appreciate your patience with this.

#### The problem: A class consisting of n students whom I'd like to pair up throughout the school year.

The number of pairs is n/2. I'd like to maximize students working with new people as much as possible, and so exhaust all possible combinations. Permutations don't matter -- student 1 + student 2 is same as student 2 + student 1.

#### What is an efficient way to build all non-repeating combinations of pairs?

One way, (suggested by Aleksei Malushkin), is to find all unique pairs, then all combinations of n/2 pair groups by brute-forcing out all non-valid groups.

Finding all unique pairs is trivial in Ruby: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].combination(2).to_a` provides an array of all 2-item pairs.

What I need, however, is to produce all groups consisting of 4 pairs each, each group without repetition of students. If the class consists of 20 students, I will need all groups of 10 pairs.

The bruteforce approach creates all combinations of pairs and throws away the ones containing repeating pairs, but this falls apart very quickly with higher numbers of students.

Here's the ruby code which solves for 8 students:

```
# Ruby 2.5.3

students = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
possible_pairs = students.combination(2).to_a  # https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-combination

puts "Possible pairs: (#{possible_pairs.size}) #{possible_pairs}"
puts "Possible pair combinations: #{possible_pairs.combination(a.size/2).size}"

groups_without_repetition = possible_pairs.
combination(students.size/2).                     # create all possible groups with students.size/2 (4) members each
each_with_object([]) do |group, accumulator|      # with each of these groups, and an "accumulator" variable starting as an empty array

  next unless group.flatten.uniq.length == (students.size)  # skip any group with repeating elements
  next if accumulator.find {|existing_group| existing_group & group != []}      # skip any group that may be found in the accumulator

  accumulator << group  # add any non-skipped group to the accumulator
end # returnn the value of the accumulator and assign it to groups_without_repetition

puts "actual pair combinations without repetition (#{groups_without_repetition.size}):"

groups_without_repetition.each_with_index do |arr, i|
  puts "#{i+1}: #{arr}"
end
```

When run, this returns:

```
Possible pairs: (28) [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [6, 7], [6, 8], [7, 8]]
Possible pair combinations: 376740
actual pair combinations without repetition (7):
1: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
2: [[1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 7], [6, 8]]
3: [[1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 8], [6, 7]]
4: [[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
5: [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 8], [4, 7]]
6: [[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 5], [4, 6]]
7: [[1, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
```

It is however not efficient. With only 12 students, the possible pairs are 66, and the possible pair combinations 90858768. I am looking to apply this to a class with 80+ participants so this approach is clearly not going to work.

#### Question 1: What would be an efficient approach to construct these combinations?

Looking at the results, it seems to me that the number of valid groups is n/2 - 1, as a student can only belong to one of n/2 possible pairs.

My sense is that it would be more efficient to *construct only the valid groups_without_repetition* instead of creating all possible groups and throwing out the non-valid ones. I am not sure how to approach this process, and would appreciate your help.

#### Question 2: How to approach this with an odd number of students?

This may need to be a separate discussion so I would not worry about it unless it has a known solution.

a. In a case where one of the students will have to participate twice to accommodate the odd number

b. In a case where one of the pairs would become a trio

In each of these cases, the students who were a part of the above non-conventional pairings, should be excluded from further exceptions for as many rotations as possible.

Comment: You need to make the question way shorter in order for people to read it.

Comment: I suggest you delete Question #2. For one, that question is not well-defined, and it would require some work to make it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is effective approach to generate such pairs - [round-robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament)

Place all students in two rows.

```
a  b  c
d  e  f
```

So pairs are `a-d, b-e, c-f`

Fix the first one and rotate others in cyclic manner

```
a  d  b
e  f  c    

a  e  d
f  c  b    

a  f  e
c  b  d

a  c  f  
b  d  e
```

So generating N-1 tours each with N/2 non-repeating pairs.

For odd number allow sole student to rest :)

or add him (right one in the top row) to the left pair to obtain the most long time between he meets both partners

```
 a  b  c  d
 e  f  g

 a-e-d, b-f, c-g
```

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the question being asked, which I understand to be: given `n` students, produce all groups of `m` pairs such that each pair appears in exactly one group (or possibly in at most one group) and each person in each group appears only once in the group. Your answer has no concept of groups.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland This approach corresponds to author's example. And perhaps to your interpretation - each pair appears in exactly one group, each person in a group appears only once in the group. May be, I did not emphasized that the first group is `([a,d],[b,e],[c,f])`, second one is `([a,e],[d,f],[b,c])` and so on

Comment: After re-reading the question I think your interpretation is correct. If there are `n` players (even) you initially have `n/2` matches. Then you shift to create `n/2` more matches, and so on. After `n-1` configurations (`n-2` shifts) all players have played every other player once. Correct? That gives you an array `arr` of `(n-1)*n/2` matches. Now if the group size is `m` matches (assume `(n-1)*n/2` is divisible by `m`), you could slice slice `arr` into arrays of `m` matches. Is it obvious that none of those arrays of `m` matches contains a person that plays more than once match in that group?

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Yes, all stuff concerning to `(n-1)*n/2 matches` is true. But I don't see a requirement to make groups of `m` matches - yes, it's possible, but it is secondary problem.

Comment: The OP does say, "What I need, however, is to produce all groups consisting of 4 pairs each, each group without repetition of students."

Comment: @Cary Swoveland  I understood this as specific case for 8 students example. Note the next sentence ` If the class consists of 20 students, I will need all groups of 10 pairs.`

Comment: MBo, thank you for referencing the round robin algorithm. Here's a simple implementation: https://gist.github.com/andreimoment/60acd522eadaed4c38ee0f275ca7f3ed I however was hoping to efficiently find all groups -- this was an intermediate step in scoring group combinations. Here's an answer in MathOverflow which helped me out, with the code resulting from it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093225/an-efficient-approach-to-combinations-of-pairs-in-groups-without-repetitions

Comment: I believe that using rotation, I could generate the desired groups in an efficient manner, so I will accept your answer, too. I am still not sure how to handle odd numbers of participants -- it is possible that a round-robin approach might be more productive with this as it may provide more control.